# how to filter data of repeater items based on radiobuttonlist in another repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, repeater

I have a shopping page where I am displaying filters on the left and side such as category, price, color, etc. and displaying products on the right hand side. I am using repeater for filter data i.e. using radio buttonlist to filter data and trying to filter data in another repeater based on radiobuttonlist in repeater1.
[this is my page look I want to filter products based on semisubcategory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhazT.png)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td style="border-right:groove;">
            <h4>Semi Sub Category</h4>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="semiSubCat1" 
                 DataSource='<%# Eval("subquery1") %>'
                 DataTextField="semiSubCategoryName"
                 DataValueField="semiSubCategoryId" runat="server">
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
       </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    var Rquery = from p in dc.ProductDatas
                 select new
                 {
                     p.productId,
                     p.proName,
                     subquery1 = from ps in dc.SemiSubCategories
                                select new { 
                                ps.semiSubCategoryId,
                               ps.semiSubCategoryName,
                                },
                    subquery2 = from sp in dc.Sizes 
                                select new {
                                sp.sizeId,
                                sp.sizeNumber,
                                },
                 };
    Repeater1.DataSource = Rquery;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
protected void semiSubCat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (semiSubCat.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string query = string.Format("select * from ProductData join SemiSubCategory on ProductData.semiSubCategory equals SemiSubCategory.semiSubCategoryId where semiSubCategoryName == semiSubCat.SelectedItem.Value"
                                                                    , sender, e);
        query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: On `semiSubCat_SelectedIndexChanged` you are querying but not binding anything back to repeater you need to bind it back to repeater. Also you need to check the code on page load as well as it may reset your repeater values.

Answer (score 0):

Try using OnCheckedChanged event

```
protected void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    
   //Filter

}
```

Comment: i tried it with the name semisubcategory please have a look